# pgfplots with big data: dimension too large

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a big file of data http://www.warcomeb.it/private/load.csv.zip with this code:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=1.12}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0,
%       xmax = 25000,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 60,
        width=19cm,
%       xtick={0,2500,5000},
%       xticklabels={0,2.5,5},
        xlabel=Time (day),
        ylabel=Temperature,
        grid=major,
        xtick scale label code/.code={},
        ]
%       \addplot [red, thick,mark=*,mark repeat=100] file [x=num,y=AccTwo]
        \addplot [red] file [x=Num, y=H1]
            {load.csv};
%       \addplot [green, thick] file [x=Num, y=H2]
%           {load.csv};
        \legend{Hive 1}
%       \legend{Hive 1,Hive 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I am compiling with lualatex and I receive this error:

```
! Dimension too large.
\pgfplotsaxisdeserializedatapointfrom@private@LUA ...
                                                  \pgfplotsaxisdeserializeda...
l.31    \end{axis}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did the answer of JPi and the corresponding comment solve your problem or do you need further assistance? Please either [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answer or edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've changed a couple of things to make it run for me.  The important bits for you are the `restrict y domain` to and `restrict x domain` to.  The irrelevant changes are that I converted it to space separated and changed the version number.  It now runs fine with `lualatex.`

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = 0,
%       xmax = 25000,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 60,
        width=19cm,
%       xtick={0,2500,5000},
%       xticklabels={0,2.5,5},
        xlabel=Time (day),
        ylabel=Temperature,
        grid=major,
        xtick scale label code/.code={},
         restrict y to domain=0:60,
         restrict x to domain=0:40
        ]
%       \addplot [red, thick,mark=*,mark repeat=100] file [x=num,y=AccTwo]
        \addplot [red] table [x =Num, y=H1]
            {load.csv};
%       \addplot [green, thick] file [x=Num, y=H2]
%           {load.csv};
        \legend{Hive 1}
%       \legend{Hive 1,Hive 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And the reason something went wrong is that one of your x coordinates is missing a period.  (should be 40.755)

Comment: I can't restrict the x domain to 0:40, because the points is the minute of ten day, so I cant't plot only the first 40 points!

Comment: Ok, restrict it to whatever it needs to be.